# Fitting an internal door lining into the void

Tags: woodworking, door-frame, interior

I live in a Victorian era flat in London. We have had one of the downstairs rooms completely damp-proofed and re-plastered and in the course of decorating today I noticed that the bottom of one of the door jambs had rotted slightly. Given the cost of what we have done to the room so far I decided to remove and replace the frame, rather than bodge it.

Having removed the door jamb in question, I discovered there was a significant gap between the door lining and the brickwork behind it. Whoever did the last install had jammed some lumps of plasterboard in there and nailed the door lining into that, but I was wondering what the best way to go about fixing the replacement door lining is?

My initial plan was to use expanding foam which would both fill the gap and also secure the frame. But the frame will be tight to the plastering so there is no gap to spray the foam into (the plastering has just been done so I would rather not chip away, though I guess I could and cover it with architrave).

Alternatively I could fix some battens to the brickwork and screw into those, but it's quite uneven so it will be hassle to get it flush and level. Or could I put the door lining in place and then squirt expanding foam through pre-drilled holes?

[image]

Any thoughts welcome! I have attached a photo but can add more (I have only removed one part of the door lining so far as you can see, but suspect the situation will be the same behind each part).

Thanks!

Comment: Is this the side of the frame with the hinges, or the side with the latch?

Answer (score 2):

I have often seen wood blocks used as the packing, screwed or nailed as convenient or even cemented into place in the brickwork.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an interior door (not accessible to anyone trying to gain access to the flat, only to those already inside the flat), the only amount of security needed is to keep the door/frame from falling off the wall.

With that in mind, I don't see any problem whatsoever with the original "lumps of plasterboard" installation or using scraps of timber to fill in the gap enough to provide a secure place to fasten the door frame without bowing it.

You're not trying to secure it against all of Attila's hoards, just preventing little Timmy from pulling the frame out of the wall and having it crash down on him.